# Microsoft Azure Maps missing atlas.control

Tags: azure, azure-maps

In documentation for Microsoft Azure Maps 1.0 JavaScript module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/?view=azure-iot-typescript-latest the loaded `atlas` module has 4 namespaces:

- control
- data
- Map
- Popup

I can easily access latter 3 of them, but atlas.control is missing.

Specifically, I need atlas.control.ZoomControl class, but can't find it? Anyone knows what's the catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and was able to reference the control module by using version 1.2 instead of 1.0 in the css and js links

Comment: Where did you get 1.2 version?

Comment: Honestly I just changed the version number in both links until it worked.

Comment: If you change the version number from "1.0" to just "1" you will always get the latest version. When you include a ".#" you access an individual release.